# What crashes Unity3D, recursion or a huge generics list?

Tags: c#, .net, list, recursion, stack-overflow

I am working with Unity3D package

Using a code which has 2 areas of interest, one of which probably causes a stack overflow and makes unity to throw a submit bug error.

1) Either a recursion which reaches 800 levels (works perfect with 600, starts to struggle at 700) as it traverses down the node-web, searching for unexplored children of those nodes. When it finds a dead end - it copy-pastes the path that lead towards this dead end into a list. Each node has about 10 children

2) Or , as a result - huge lists carrying paths in other list, example 58 000 cells full of other lists (on top of that - procedure is done for every node in the scene).

**a)** I though that it might have been a recursion, that I need to translate it into a stack form, but now I am more and more inclined to think that this because of the huge lists. Should I split my list into smaller ones? Can I do something to avoid this stack overflow, if it is one?

**b)** With that, could you please explain if list size matter for stack and can they overflow it?

I got 8 GB of RAM, but resource manager said Unity only uses 1.5GB before it crashes

Please advise!

Thank you very much!

Comment: @Blorgbeard, is it because of huge lists?  :D Thank you!

Comment: It's hard to say. Do you have an actual error message? I'm going offline now for the day, but I'd advise you to add a bit more detail about the crash and hopefully someone else will help. Also, tag your question with the language and framework you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having re-structured my pile of code, biting out those lists, leaving out empty spaces instead, the problem still persisted, so it is indeed, a recursion.

Everybody who is interested further on, please follow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567287/recursion-into-stack-form-preserving-a-search-path-towards-ends-of-recursion?noredirect=1#comment32577555_21567287) for a recursion-to-stack conversion, taking into account Path to each of the dead-ends of the web a recursion had to go through.